# Can we do Sandhyavandanam in Bedroom?

Tags: rituals, yajur-veda, vedic-rituals, sandhyavandanam, vedic-chanting

Is there a restriction in doing Sandhyavandanam in particular place or it can be done anywhere?

Comment: See this answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35944/4732